# How to achieve web site customization like iGoogle?

Tags: stylesheet

I'd like to know how to achieve web site customization like iGoogle (in particular I'd like to know how to drag/drop parts of web page (a.k.a. "prtlets") to different corners) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question [how-to-use-draggable-sections-like-on-igoogle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603059/how-to-use-draggable-sections-like-on-igoogle).

Check out the NETTUTs tutorial linked there by ceejayoz. It is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is this Asp.Net? If so you can check out the following web-parts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in different ways in different platforms ...

But they all use advanced levels of javascript and css manipulation ...

in ASP.NET for example there is a great example called dropthings

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/Web20Portal.aspx

It is a great example for how to achieve same level of customization